# Check in a template if an action is in the allow list

Tags: cakephp

I don't want to check if a user is logged in - which normally is done. I want to check if the current view is in the allow list set in the controller.

```
$this->Auth->allow('testresults', 'testlist' , 'detaillist',
```

How can I determine if an action is allowed?

Comment: Use the in_array php function. You can get the current view with $this->params['action']

Comment: I've edited your question - but please update it to better indicate what you're doing. At least 2 people don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check.

```
 $action = $this->request->params['action'];

        if(in_array($action, ['testresults', 'testlist', ''])){
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code anywhere to see the actions that are allowed:

```
debug(AuthComponent::$allowedActions);exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pass info *to* the view

[allowed actions are stored in a public property](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L189-L195), so in your controller code, you can do:

```
$allowed = $this->Auth->allowedActions;
$this->set('allowedActions', $allowed);
```

Then simply expect that array in the view.

In principle view templates should not need to ask for information - they should only act on what they receive.

Comment: Yes, it is true that views just act on what they receive but what I want to do is hide twitter feeds and not need code in the layout to pages that is private to speed page load up.

Comment: You haven't said anything which modifies my answer, or edited the question as requested above.

Comment: Came up with a hybrid of code..   `code`$this->Auth->allow('index', 'get_all_job_type','apply_for_job','product','add_to_basket','basket','detail','jobinfo','view_all_active_job','view_all_expired_job','readmark','results');

    $pagepermission = 'private';
    $allowed = $this->Auth->allowedActions;
    $action = $this->request->params['action'];

        if(in_array($action, $allowed)){
            $pagepermission = 'public';
        }
     $this->set('pagepermission',$pagepermission);

Comment: Please both update your question, and write an answer with whatever your solution was (do not write it in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a hybrid code solutions for now.. in the beforefilter..

```
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'page1','page2'..);

$pagepermission = 'private';
$allowed = $this->Auth->allowedActions;
$action = $this->request->params['action'];

    if(in_array($action, $allowed)){
        $pagepermission = 'public';
    }
 $this->set('pagepermission',$pagepermission);
```